# DidSelectRowAtIndexPath not working in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with Static cells (shown below).
[image]

I want my application to log the current user out when they select log out, obviously. For the number of sections I have the following code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rows: Int = 0

        let numberOfRowsAtSection: [Int] = [2, 2, 1]

        if section < numberOfRowsAtSection.count {
            rows = numberOfRowsAtSection[section]
        }

        return rows
    }
```

I would normally do didSelectRowAtIndexPath to logout this user so I tried the following code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if (indexPath.row) == 4 {
            PFUser.logOut()
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

It is not working because the logout is actually at index 0 so when I click either edit profile or about it logs me out because there are 3 index 0's so to speak. I am not sure exactly how I can combat this issue, I tried the code above with no success - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as shown:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if ((indexPath.section == 2) && (indexPath.row == 0)) {
        PFUser.logOut()
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the section AND row number

```
if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    /* do log out */
}
```